# Python compatibility: Catching exceptions

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, compatibility, python-2.5

I have an application, that needs to be working in all "modern" Python versions, which means `2.5`-`3.2`. I don't want two code bases, so `2to3` is not an option.

Consider something like this:

```
def func(input):
    if input != 'xyz':
        raise MyException(some_function(input))
    return some_other_function(input)
```

How can I catch this exception, to get access to the exception object?
`except MyException, e:` is not valid in Python 3, and `except MyException as e:` is not valid in python 2.5.

Clearly it could have been possible to return the exception object, but I hope, i don't have to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This concern is addressed [in the Py3k docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/pyporting.html#capturing-the-currently-raised-exception). The solution is to check [sys.exc_info()](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info):

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    raise Exception()
except Exception:
    import sys
    print(sys.exc_info()) # => (<type 'exceptions.Exception'>, Exception(), <traceback object at 0x101c39830>) 
    exc = sys.exc_info()[1]
    print(type(exc)) # => <type 'exceptions.Exception'>
    print([a for a in dir(exc) if not a.startswith('__')]) # => ['args', 'message']
```